# ASP.NET Identity2 and DataContext Injecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, asp.net-identity

I have a multi tier web application working on ASP.NET MVC 5.
I have completely separated Infrastructure (DAL) from UI using a business layer.
any time UI function needs a DAL access, it calls my business service and the business service does it's job and if needed returns a result.

For IoC, Business services are injected into UI project and Infrastructure injected into Business service using Ninject

I need my UI project to have exactly 0 reference to my infrastructure project, but when it comes to using ASP.NET Identity 2 framework, It needs reference to infrastructure for `ApplicationDbContext`.

There are two reference to my Infrastructure project one from IdentityConfig.cs in

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

and another from Startup.Auth.cs in

```
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

what is the solution for this?

This is the schema of the Architecture I used: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With big thanks to @Andrei M for his great help and guidance, 
I Solved this as below:

First Step: I Created An IDbContext Interface in my Domain Layer. (because from presentation we don't have access to my Infrastructure Layer)

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
}
```

Second Step: Implement IDbContext Interface in my ApplicationDbContext in Infrastructure Layer.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDbContext
```

Third Step: As In my Project, the only layer that has reference to my Infrastructure Layer, is Business layer. so for use my ApplicationDbContext in my owin startup class in presentation layer, I need a Factory class in my business layer to return me a Db Context.

```
public static class DbContextFactory
{
    public static IDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Forth Step: Changing the Owin Startup class to use My DbContextFactory Class whenever it needs a DbContext.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(DbContextFactory.Create);
```

Final Step: the only thing that remains is to change IdentityConfig.cs to don't reference directly to ApplicationDbContext in it's create  method.

```
 public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var myUserStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>((IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>) context.Get<IDbContext>());
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(myUserStore);
```

Actually for this step I have two solution, first is what you see above (Cast to IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>)
second is Cast to DbContext. I Don't know if I'll have any problem with casting to DbContext (in System.Data.Entity namespace) later, and for now I use the first solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces and factory methods will solve your problem. Whenever you want to create object - use simple factory that returns an interface of your object. And whenever you want to abstract from concrete implementation - use interfaces.

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory
{
    public static IApplicationDbContext Create(IOwinContext owinContext)
    {
        return ApplicationDbContext.Create(owinContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I create a factory class that it generate an object of type ApplicationDbContext, I forced to add a reference to my Infrastructure project.

Comment: @mesut you should generate an object of type `IApplicationDbContext` (please note it is an interface)

Comment: So I'm going to add a new Interface named IDbContext in my domain layer, Then implement this interface with my ApplicationDbContext in my Infrastructure layer, then add a new DbContextFactory class in my Business layer, after all in my startup.auth.cs replace ApplicationDbContext.Create with DbContextFactory.Create (this function returns a IDbContext) is it true_

Comment: That not work!!!, It fails to send IOwinContext to ApplicationUserManager's Create Function. Error is Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: context

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved that this way:
var myUserStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>((ApplicationDbContext) context.Get<IDbContext>());

And moved IdentityConfig.cs to My Business tier, and it solved. But there is another thing, that every time with any request (ajax or http) to my site, My Factory's create method is calling!!!

Comment: @mesut use static Lazy field if you want your class to be initialized only once.

Comment: the default asp.net mvc 5 template with Identity2 is also calls ApplicationDbContext's create method for every request.